# GeoXML3 accessing KML attribute datas

Tags: javascript, xml, kml, geoxml3

My KML File has the following format:

```
<Placemark>
<Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
<ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#seb">
    <SimpleData name="PR0">CORS</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="PR1">BRB</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="PR2">F15</SimpleData>
</SchemaData></ExtendedData>
  <MultiGeometry><Polygon><altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>71.0035714700001,38.4757616580001 71.0567352510001,38.398144523 71.1035044220001,38.422803406000138.4764993150001 71.0035714700001,38.4757616580001</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
```

I want to be able to access the the extended data fields from the kml which I will be using for further processing and indexing the polygons for later use and searching.

As this post states, the variables can be access from placemark.vars.val but I could not get this since vars is undefined.

[Load kml extendeddata into variable with Geoxml3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537680/load-kml-extendeddata-into-variable-with-geoxml3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replying to **geocodezip** reply above...

You approach works but the problem is the kml is produced frequently. Making the changes you mentioned might be a bit difficult because of the content of the `<SimpleData>` tag which contains the value as text where the expected format is `<Data><value></value></Data>`.

Best way would be to create a php or any program that parse the kml and make the changes. I decided to edit the GeoXML3.js parser to look for SimpleData instead of Data tags at line number 639

```
var dataNodes = getElementsByTagName(extDataNodes[0], 'Data');
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently the kmz branch of geoxml3 handles `ExtendedData` in the format defined in the [KML Reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/extendeddata#entity-replacement-for-extended-data-elements)

If you modify your KML to that format (`<Data>` instead of `<SimpleData>`, `<value>` tags around the value), it will work as is.

```
<Placemark>
  <Style>
    <LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color><width>2</width></LineStyle>
    <PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle>
    <BalloonStyle>
      <text>
      <![CDATA[$[name]<br>PR0: $[PR0]<br>PR1: $[PR1]<br>PR2: $[PR2]]]>
      </text>
    </BalloonStyle>
  </Style>
  <ExtendedData>
  <SchemaData schemaUrl="#seb">
    <Data name="PR0">
      <value>CORS</value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="PR1">
      <value>BRB</value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="PR2">
      <value>F15</value>
    </Data></SchemaData>
  </ExtendedData>
  <MultiGeometry>
    <Polygon>
      <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
      <outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing>
        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
        <coordinates>71.0035714700001,38.4757616580001 71.0567352510001,38.398144523 71.1035044220001,38.422803406000138.4764993150001 71.0035714700001,38.4757616580001
        </coordinates>
      </LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
  </MultiGeometry>
</Placemark>
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/qcq878sg/2/)

The other option is to modify [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) to support `<SimpleData>` tags in your format (it is open source).

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
    map: map,
    singleInfoWindow: true
  });
  geoXml.parseKmlString(kmlStr);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
var kmlStr = '<Placemark><Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color><width>2</width></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle><BalloonStyle><text><![CDATA[$[name]<br>PR0: $[PR0]<br>PR1: $[PR1]<br>PR2: $[PR2]]]></text></BalloonStyle></Style><ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#seb"><Data name="PR0"><value>CORS</value></Data><Data name="PR1"><value>BRB</value></Data><Data name="PR2"><value>F15</value></Data></SchemaData></ExtendedData><MultiGeometry><Polygon><altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>71.0035714700001,38.4757616580001 71.0567352510001,38.398144523 71.1035044220001,38.422803406000138.4764993150001 71.0035714700001,38.4757616580001</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry></Placemark>';
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/geocodezip/geoxml3/master/kmz/geoxml3.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```