# data not displaying from KML file

Tags: google-maps, kml

I am trying to display custom info from a KML file onto google maps.  I am using [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kml) and for the most part it is working.  I however cannot seem to add an address after then name in the BallonStyle.  The code I am using is below.

Any help is appreciated

```
<BalloonStyle>
    <text><![CDATA[<h3>$[name], $[address]</h3>]]></text>
</BalloonStyle>

<name>Untitled layer</name>
  <Placemark>
    <name>Campus Honda</name>
<address>506 Finlayson St, Victoria, BC V8T 5C8</address>
    <styleUrl>#icon-1899-0288D1-nodesc</styleUrl>


<Point>
      <coordinates>
        -123.3737904,48.4445293,0
      </coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#supported-elements), the Google Maps API KmlLayer doesn't support entity replacements.

> `<BalloonStyle>`  partially   only `<text>` is supported
>
> `<ExtendedData>`  partially   untyped `<Data>` only, no `<SimpleData>` or `<Schema>`, and **entity replacements of the form $[dataName] are not supported**.

You could try the 3rd party KML parser [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) (or an equivalent).

Related question: [GeoXML3 accessing KML attribute datas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516114/geoxml3-accessing-kml-attribute-datas).

But that may have performance issues with large/complex KML.

(disclaimer: I currently maintain geoxml3, although there isn't much activity there)