# How to store extended data from parsed kml files into variables

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, geoxml3

I parse a kml file through geoxml3 where the placemarks have extended data fields. Using the geoxml.js from the kmz branch (trying to follow the solution here: [Load kml extendeddata into variable with Geoxml3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537680/load-kml-extendeddata-into-variable-with-geoxml3)), I still find that geoXmlDoc.gpolylines[0].title works but geoXmlDoc.gpolylines[0].vars.val is undefined. Placemark formatting for reference:

```
<Placemark>
  <name>Left to Right</name>
  <description><![CDATA[One Way: True<br>Crossing: false<br>Closure: True]]></description>
  <styleUrl>#line-000000-1200</styleUrl>
  <ExtendedData>
    <Data name="One Way">
      <value>True</value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="Crossing">
      <value>0</value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="Closure">
      <value>True</value>
    </Data>
  </ExtendedData>
  <LineString>
    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
    <coordinates>
      115.8350241,-31.928985,0
      115.8409465,-31.9267996,0
      115.8470404,-31.9297863,0
      115.8533061,-31.9272367,0
    </coordinates>
  </LineString>
</Placemark>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this by adding this last line in geoxml3's polyoptions variable (at line 1255).

```
var polyOptions = geoXML3.combineOptions(parserOptions.polylineOptions, {
  map:           parserOptions.map,
  path:          path,
  strokeColor:   kmlStrokeColor.color,
  strokeWeight:  placemark.style.line.width,
  strokeOpacity: kmlStrokeColor.opacity,
  title:         placemark.name,
  visible:       placemark.visibility,
  polyDesc:      placemark.description,
  eData:         placemark.vars.val
});
```

Then I was able to access the variable with geoXmlDoc.gpolylines[x].eData['Closure'], where 'Closure' was the name of my extended data field.